# Google Analytics Report with Multiple Link URL Filters

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

How can I create a Google Analytics 4 Exploration where I can track multiple Link URLs?

Currently, I can only track one Link URL:

[image]

But if I try adding another Link URL, I get:

[image]

Basically, I'm looking for a way to add multiple exact Link URLs to see the results for each one.

Edit: Someone suggested using a RegEx pattern, but that wouldn't work in this case since I have many URLs that follow the same pattern I wish to exclude.

My URLs follow a pattern like this:

https://www.example.com/?id=9021
https://www.example.com/?id=9022
https://www.example.com/?id=9023

There's thousands of URLs with that pattern. Ideally, I would like to filter a handful of URLs on the same report and only get results for those URLs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to match multiple urls would be to leverage RegEx pattern matching.

You can do something like `.*foo.*` and it will match any urls that have foo in it.

I suggest reading up and becoming familiar with it because it can be a powerful tool

Edit: There are multiple ways to handle matching the IDs provided.

`.*id=(9021|9022|9023).*`

`.*id=90(21|22|23).*`

`.*id=9[0-9][2-5][0-9]`

All three of these match different ways. The first matches those specific IDs. This would be harder to manage if you have a bunch of them.

The second one matches for the same IDs but is looking first at IDs beginning with 90 and ending with the 3 specific ones.

The last would capture a lot more urls.The frist two positions in the id can be between 90 and 99. The last two positions could be between 20-59.

Comment: The reason I can't use that method is because I have many URLs that follow the same pattern that I actually want to exclude. Literally, the only distinction in the URLs is an id query string parameter. That's the reason I need a way to filter by multiple EXACT URLs inclusively, not exclusively.

Comment: @GTSJoe so why not write a regex that includes your "id query string parameter" and exclude the rest?

Comment: Because the id in the URLs have several different values. like so: https://www.example.com/?id=9021 https://www.example.com/?id=9022 https://www.example.com/?id=9023 If you think it's still possible, please provide an example.

Comment: `.*id=(9022|9021|9023)$` is one way to handle it. This would get any urls that end with the query parameter in the parenthesis. Another would be `.*id=90(21|22|23).*`. This would match urls that contain IDs with 90 followed by one of the other options in the parenthesis. RegEx is going to be the easiest, most flexible way to match multiple urls. @GTSJoe, how many URLs are you trying to match?

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I had to modify the regex quite a bit, but this was the right approach. For reference, this is the regex I ended up going with: https://www\.example\.com/WorkingDocs/Browse\.aspx\?id=(8024|8025|8026)&dbid=0&repo=WorkingDocs